# Creating a dojo widget to load another page via request

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want this widget to show what is on the http://localhost:8080/webapp/trending page wherever I have this:

```
<div data-dojo-type="js/widget/SATrending"></div>
```

Right now it doesn't load the content onto the page and I'm not sure what I have missed.

JS (js/widget/SATrending):

```
require([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dojo/dom-construct",
"dojo/parser",
"dojo/ready",
"dijit/_WidgetBase",
"dojo/request"],
function(declare, domConstruct, parser, ready, _WidgetBase, request) {
    declare("js/widget/SATrending",[_WidgetBase], {
        top: 10,
        constructor: function() {
        },
        postMixInProperties: function() {
        },
        buildRendering: function() {
            var txt;

            request("http://localhost:8080/webapp/trending").then(
                    function(text) {
                        txt: text;
                    },
                    function(error) {});

            this.domNode = txt;
        },
        /*
         * Setters
         */
        setTopAttr: function(top) {
            this.top = top;
        },
        postCreate: function() {
        },
        startUp: function() {
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems.  Firstly, in your success callback, `txt: text` is not valid JavaScript.  Secondly, you probably want to be assigning `txt` to `this.domNode.innerHTML`, not just `this.domNode`.

Most importantly, however, `this.domNode = txt;` will never do what you're probably expecting it to, since `txt` is *not actually updated* until the request completes asynchronously, but you are setting `this.domNode` immediately after sending the request.

Here is an example of restructuring your `buildRendering` code into something that should actually work:

```
this.inherited(arguments);
var self = this;

request("http://localhost:8080/webapp/trending").then(
    function(text) {
        self.domNode.innerHTML = text;
    },
    function(error) {});
```

Other notes about your code:

- Don't forget to call `this.inherited(arguments)` in widget lifecycle methods (postMixInProperties, buildRendering, postCreate, startup) if you define them.  (`constructor` chains by default so you shouldn't call it there.)
- `startup` should have a lowercase u.
- You could probably use [ContentPane](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html) with its `href` property to more easily do what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I would have used a ContentPane but I was trying to wrap my head around creating widgets in Dojo and I wanted to later add some more functionality to this widget. Your code worked for my intended purposes